# How to overload class member type depending on argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, typing, pyright

I recently learned I can overload return type using `Literal[True]` and `Literal[False]` argument. I am implementing my own `subprocess.Popen`-ish interface and I am not able to overload `self.stdin` return type to be `IO[bytes]` or `IO[str]` depending on the value of `text` in the constructor. I am using pyright for static type checking.

I have tried the following:

```
from typing import IO, Literal, Optional, overload


class MyPopen:
    @overload
    def __init__(self, text: Literal[False] = False):
        self.stdin: Optional[IO[bytes]]

    @overload
    def __init__(self, text: Literal[True] = True):
        self.stdin: Optional[IO[str]]

    def __init__(self, text: bool = False):
        self.stdin = None


pp = MyPopen(text=True)
assert pp.stdin
pp.stdin.write("text")    # should be ok
pp.stdin.write(b"text")   # should error
pp = MyPopen(text=False)
assert pp.stdin
pp.stdin.write("text")    # should error
pp.stdin.write(b"text")   # should be ok
```

However, it assumes `pp.stdin` to be `IO[str]` twice, and the declaration stdin is obscured:

```
$ pyright /dev/stdin <1.py
/dev/stdin
  /dev/stdin:7:14 - error: Declaration "stdin" is obscured by a declaration of the same name (reportRedeclaration)
  /dev/stdin:20:1 - error: No overloads for "write" match the provided arguments (reportCallIssue)
  /dev/stdin:20:16 - error: Argument of type "Literal[b"text"]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "str" in function "write"
    "Literal[b"text"]" is incompatible with "str" (reportArgumentType)
  /dev/stdin:24:1 - error: No overloads for "write" match the provided arguments (reportCallIssue)
  /dev/stdin:24:16 - error: Argument of type "Literal[b"text"]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "str" in function "write"
    "Literal[b"text"]" is incompatible with "str" (reportArgumentType)
5 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

How can I overload class instance member type depending on the value of argument?

Note how it works with subprocess.Popen:

```
import subprocess
pp = subprocess.Popen("", text=True)
assert pp.stdout
pp.stdout.write("text")   # ok
pp.stdout.write(b"text")  # error
pp = subprocess.Popen("", text=False)
assert pp.stdout
pp.stdout.write("text")   # error
pp.stdout.write(b"text")  # ok
```

I tried reading subprocess source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L1015 , but I do not know where type annotations are stored.

Comment: The expected results for the second test case seem to be inverted.

Comment: By the way, the type annotations for `subprocess` can be found [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/subprocess.pyi), in a package called `typeshed`.

Comment: Rather than using a Boolean value as code for text or binary, you should pass the one you really want directly, although here, it's not so much a choice between a binary stream and a text stream as it is a choice between wrapping a binary stream in a codec or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is valid use of `@overload`. It is used to specify more precise signatures for functions, not to conditionally set the type of attributes.

However, you can create two empty subclasses, one for `str` and one for `bytes`, then let `MyPopen.__new__()` return either of those and use `@overload` on *that* instead. The subclasses don't have to do anything other than serving as types; the logic will still be defined in `MyPopen`.

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=434fd7213fc01046a65c5e551905d41c), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBA%2BjwFcAuCQFM5QJYQA5hCSgEMA7UsJYpLMUgZwChHRIokBPXLUgc2zwEiASQDyAGigAZLEjQhiAG0lgAbvMVhiAE2aMAxFFEgoAFSgBeM1zQA1YiAAUAclPPJ9JCEkAjDnPoASgBuKABjRWJ6eigAWS4wXDRSRwBxZPksMIBtUwBdQIAuKAA6MsYIqJj4gAVE5Nzix09vKD8AwLzC5igoT20eYrFcvKgAHygAOTo0HqhDaYB3KA4wBHCyKAR6NCgAATUNLW0AQjmD9RBNHUZe7TRgWBhSNEW4Rwj6STkADyRimRyBSKbIAMSUOwKUAAtAA%2BWAAIX8aHodSSpG6vV6ZRK50OV2Otyg90ecBebxgH0UX3YaD%2BANk8iUuRACDQULhsAAyl40clMVicXjLtddHcHk9ye9PoEYfCYEiAnyMUTseUiSTJa9pdTvnT-m0wGBFJYoODqWhZZyFcjUfVSONubz7QLelhHr8iFgYqZWWhXVj6AgfJVoqaYDyQMrVVA0BaA70gyHImGrDalfa5r1DABVHZQMA%2BABWaDCRAI7BsxSwvAo6HYYCguCqfS8WSIEDA9xjPE8ZDCuysQaSTkCJTJ2spSdDQR7DCopAHJX6PFN0xeWag6BQIAdvYXA7mmsWIEZzTjwBUyFwyGKpit8PX-pjQuYM6dUftjlq9uyLQKArNtEejvumKLKt%2BHDKtk7QogBRJAUwzC4LgACMpo-uijiBIwVTyEQKGocuSADKQjCEcRpElCeZ4AESerRspYoY8jgCAxS0YCTIgs4nrOHktHYDEPBhJAzY0D4ii7IssgABZQLRsH0LR5FoZRPDUaeciOD49H6oxzFQMAPCzKpABMGFQV%2BnoWOaOw4XhhBNrgZnqWRKGuSupCaXRDFMdmsYgGxHFccC2S8fq-GCd62CLmJ1BYJJ0lyQpSkqR5bk%2Bdpul%2BYZxkbqpADMlkQTZvpskxuHRPhzmFW5RWZTR2l6X8Bl5SZDVeVlaA6S1SBtfMgXBQpoXMjl%2BkCUJsWiXgCVJVAMlIPJtEtCpQA))</sub>

```py
# Or T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes); class MyPopen(Generic[T]): ...
class MyPopen[T: (str, bytes)]:

  stdin: IO[T] | None

  # Now you can use @overload!

  @overload
  def __new__(cls, text: Literal[False] = ...) -> _BytesPopen:
    ...

  @overload
  def __new__(cls, text: Literal[True]) -> _StrPopen:
    ...

  def __new__(cls, text: bool = False) -> _BytesPopen | _StrPopen:
    if text is True:
      subclass = _StrPopen
    else:
      subclass = _BytesPopen

    # Use `object.__new__()` or `type: ignore` to pass strict mode
    instance = super().__new__(subclass)
    instance.stdin = None

    return instance

  def write(self, output: T) -> None:
    ...
```

```py
class _StrPopen(MyPopen[str]):
  pass

class _BytesPopen(MyPopen[bytes]):
  pass
```

The results will then be:

```py
pp = MyPopen()
assert pp.stdin
pp.stdin.write("text")    # error: "Literal['text']" is incompatible with "bytes"
pp.stdin.write(b"text")   # fine
```

```py
pp = MyPopen(text=False)
assert pp.stdin
pp.stdin.write("text")    # error: "Literal['text']" is incompatible with "bytes"
pp.stdin.write(b"text")   # fine
```

```py
pp = MyPopen(text=True)
assert pp.stdin
pp.stdin.write("text")    # fine
pp.stdin.write(b"text")   # error: "Literal[b"text"]" is incompatible with "str"
```

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure, if you want to do so. I learned the pattern from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zsV0_QrfTw); it might also be helpful to you.

Comment: Awesome answer, the only nitpick: you don't need the third overload! Use `def __new__(cls, text: Literal[False] = ...) -> _BytesPopen:` in the first, and this fill account for both 0-arg and 1-arg cases. This matches the implementation (where the argument is indeed defaulted) closer.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the `__init__` by providing the self type. You have to provide overload for each case.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import IO, Literal, overload, cast, TypeVar, Generic, Union, BinaryIO
from io import TextIOWrapper
import sys

def my_binary_stream_wrapper() -> BinaryIO:
  return sys.stdin.buffer

T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)
class MyPopen(Generic[T]):    
  @overload
  def __init__(self: MyPopen[str], text: Literal[False]) -> None:
    ...

  @overload
  def __init__(self: MyPopen[bytes], text: Literal[True]) -> None:
    ...

  @overload
  def __init__(self: MyPopen[bytes]) -> None:
    ...

  def __init__(self, text: bool = False):
     stream = my_binary_stream_wrapper()
     if text:
         stream = TextIOWrapper(stream)
     self.stdin: IO[T] | None = cast(IO[T], stream)


pp1 = MyPopen()
assert pp1.stdin
pp1.stdin.write("text")    # error: "Literal['text']" is incompatible with "bytes"
pp1.stdin.write(b"text")   # fine

pp2 = MyPopen(text=False)
assert pp2.stdin
pp2.stdin.write("text")    # error: "Literal['text']" is incompatible with "bytes"
pp2.stdin.write(b"text")   # fine

pp3 = MyPopen(text=True)  
assert pp3.stdin
pp3.stdin.write("text")    # fine
pp3.stdin.write(b"text")   # error: "Literal[b"text"]" is incompatible with "str"
```

Note that **3** overloads of `__new__` are needed - one for `True`, one for `False`, and one for *dynamic boolean value*. Note how `cast(IO[T]` is used to assign to the member to let the static type checker know it is in fact `T`.